# spectrum of an element of unital banach algebra is closed set

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and $a \in A$. Then the spectrum $\sigma(a)$ and set of invertible elements $\text{Inv}(A)$ are defined as:
$$
\begin{align}
&\text{Inv}(A):=\{a\in A~|~a \text{ is invertible}\}\\
&\sigma(a):=\{\lambda \in \mathbb C~|~\lambda 1-a \notin \text{Inv}(A)\}.
\end{align}
$$
I want to show that $\sigma(a)$ is closed subset of $\mathbb C$. But I already know that $\text{Inv}(A)$ is an open subset of $A$, since $A$ is a Banach algebra. I know there are many approaches to show that $\sigma(a)$ is closed, but I want to show by assuming $\text{Inv}(A)$ is an open subset of $A$.

Taking the set $\mathbb C-\sigma(a)$, we have to show that this set is open provided $\text{Inv}(A)$ is an open. Can you please give me some hint?

Answer (score 3):

If $\lambda \in \rho(a)$, then $\lambda 1 - a \in \mathrm{Inv}(A)$. Because $\mathrm{Inv}(A)$ is open, an $\epsilon > 0$ exists such that $b \in \mathrm{Inv}(A)$ if $||b-\lambda 1 + a|| < \epsilon$. In particular, $b = \mu 1 - a \in \mathrm{Inv}(A)$ for $|\mu - \lambda| < \epsilon$ (assuming $||1|| = 1$). Thus, $\rho(a)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Consider the continuous(!) map $r\colon \mathbf C \to A$, $\lambda \mapsto \lambda 1 - a$. How can you express $\rho(a) := \mathbf C - \sigma(a)$ in terms of $r$ and $\mathrm{Inv}(A)$?

Comment: Okay, then we can write $\mathbb C-\sigma(a)=r^{-1}\left(T\right),$ where  $T=\{\lambda 1-a \in \text{Inv}(A)~|~ \lambda \in \mathbb C\}.$ But how can I show $T$ is open here?

Comment: @abcdmath Actually it’s still true that $C\setminus\sigma(a)=r^{-1}(\mathrm{Inv}(A))$ which is open. It is still true that $T$ is open but you didn’t need to worry about that

Answer (score 0):

Of course if we have an invertible element perturbing it slightly ([see claim 6.6](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ejs129/PDFs/teaching/MAT520_fall_2023/MAT520_Lecture_Notes.pdf)) will not change the fact that it is still invertible. This is precisely Janik's answer. However, it is also not hard to find the inverse explicitly and this is what I will do here.

Suppose $\lambda_o\in \rho(a)=\sigma(a)^C$. We know there is a certain $c$ such that:

$$c(a-\lambda_o 1)=(a-\lambda_o 1)c=1$$

Let us play a little with this:

$$(a-(\lambda-\lambda+\lambda_o) 1)c=1\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad (a-\lambda 1)c=1+(\lambda_o-\lambda)c $$

By the Neumann series ([lemma 6.5 here](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ejs129/PDFs/teaching/MAT520_fall_2023/MAT520_Lecture_Notes.pdf)), we know that if we take $\lambda$ satisfying $|\lambda_o-\lambda|<\frac{1}{|c|}$, then $1-c(\lambda-\lambda_o)$ will be invertible and we have:

$$(a-\lambda 1) c(1-c(\lambda-\lambda_o))^{-1}=1$$

Doing the same computation we find that for $|\lambda_o-\lambda|<1/|c|$:

$$c(1-c(\lambda-\lambda_o))^{-1} \quad \text{is the right inverse of $(a-\lambda 1)$}$$

$$(1-c(\lambda-\lambda_o))^{-1} c \quad \text{is the left inverse of $(a-\lambda 1)$}$$

Elements with left and right inverses have the same inverse in an algebra. Indeed, if: $lx=xr=1$, we need: $$l=l1=l(xr)=(lx)r=1r=r$$

Thus, we conclude $\sigma(a)\subset \mathbb{C}$ must be really closed as its complement is open.